# How do I assign RunSettings in VS2019 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, visual-studio-2019, runsettings

In Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, assigning RunSettings files can typically be done here, under "Test" > "Test Settings":

[image]

However, I don't see anything relevant when going to "Test" on Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise (Preview 4.0):

[image]

Where can I assign the RunSettings file to run with in the Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting was changed in VS 2019 - you can find it in Test Explorer tool Window

See the [docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file.md) for the exact instructions.